# How to parse a JSON secret to YAML in Vault?

Tags: kubernetes, consul, hashicorp-vault

I have a secret in Vault which is really a "complex" structure of JSON, meaning it's not just a key/value but there are several keys at different sublevels.

I need to somehow get this secret and convert it to the YAML representation of that JSON. If it was a simple structure (like several k/v at the same level), I could use something as simple as

```
      {{- with secret "secret/foo" -}}
          {{ range $k, $v := .Data.data }}
            {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
          {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```

however, as this is not the case, and the structure of the JSON is complex, trying to come up with a template is rather impossible.

However, I found that Vault uses Consul templates, and Consul has a parseYAML function, so my question is, how can I template this so that I get all the content of `.Data.data` and translate it into YAML?

I have tried several approaches similar to this one below:

```
{{- with secret "secret/foo" -}}
{{ .Data.data| parseYAML }}
{{- end }}
```

but I'm always getting the same error `wrong type for value; expected string; got map[string]interface {}"`

UPDATE

Sample yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-foo: 'secret/foo'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-secret-foo: |
          {{- with secret "secret/foo" -}}
          {{ .Data.data| parseYAML }}
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'app'
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: 'app:1.0.0'
      serviceAccountName: app
```

where `secret/foo` is a long JSON with no clear structure. A random example (actual JSON is about 300 lines I think).

```
{
  "a": {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": {
      "a": "a",
      "b": {
        "c": "c"
      },
      "d": "a"
    },
    "e": {
      "a": {
        "b": {
          "c": {
            "a": "a",
            "b": "b"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is your `.Data.data` a HCL2 Map or a JSON String?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I stored in Vault a JSON, but the output once the secret is retrieved is definitively not a JSON. It follows a format like: `key:map[key:map[key:value] key2:value key3:map[key4:map[.......`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the HCL2 format you refer to. Basically a JSON in which the `{` are replaced with `map[`, and the `,` with a whitespace.

Comment: So that sounds like HCL2 Map, which would be properly converted to YAML with `parseYAML`. I would speculate that your Kubernetes manifest expects a String type for the value, and you are not passing a String. Seeing 1. the structure of your secret 2. the Kubernetes manifest snippet would both reduce the amount of speculation.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the secret is really big, it's not really a "secret" per se, but as the app was poorly designed, the devs mixed secrets with standard settings. So, just assume a random JSON with no clear structure, for example `{"a":{"a":"a","b":"b","c":{"a":"a","b":{"c":"c"},"d":"a"},"e":{"a":{"b":{"c":{"a":"a","b":"b"}}}}}}`. The Kubernetes' yaml is nothing special, standard Pod definition with Vault's annocations to read the secret.

Comment: So you probably just need to return a single key-value pair from the Map for the Kubernetes attribute, but without seeing the snippet I cannot be sure.

Comment: @MattSchuchard as I had already said, there is nothing special in the manifest. The relevant data is already in the question. But well, if you really think it can help you in coming up with a solution for this, there you have an edited version of the question with a manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just figure this out.

```
{{- with secret "secret/foo" -}}
{{ .Data.data| toYAML }}
{{- end }}
```

this is correct, but instead of `parseYAML` the right function is `toYAML`.